# 3TB Fusiondrive split, Need help

Tags: bootcamp, fusion-drive

My Fusiondrive has split and I really need your help.
I made a backup and I am ready to delete everything clear slate.
How can I get everything fixed?
Thanks a lot for your help.

```
diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            2.5 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data 200gb                   208.6 GB   disk1s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data 200gb2                  208.5 GB   disk1s5
   6:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk1s6
   7:       Microsoft Basic Data 4                       354.4 MB   disk1s7
   8:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk1s8
   9:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk1s9
  10:                  Apple_HFS 3                       67.5 GB    disk1s10
  11:       Microsoft Basic Data 5                       471.9 MB   disk1s11
  12:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk1s12
  13:                  Apple_HFS 1                       471.9 MB   disk1s13
  14:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk1s14

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +2.6 TB     disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 E6BEBC47-429D-4A0B-BBAA-78283E95CE02
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
```

Comment: will a reinstall of OSX delete everything and fix the fusion drive? Just looking for the fastest way. Data is already saved on an external HDD

Answer (score 1):

I managed to delete everything in the command line and i now have 2 drives (ssd and hdd). I then installed OS X on the SSD and this is how it looks like.

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE          
IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS 1                       3.0 TB     disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk1
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                120.5 GB   disk1s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
```